# How do I Create DataTable from with multiple nested JSON Objects in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json

Every time i am getting a dynamic JSON data, it can be an JSON array or a simple JSON object or nested JSON objects.

I am trying to de-serialize and convert the JSON object/array into a DataTable for further processing using Newtonsoft.Json.

My Current code is

```
public DataTable ConvertJson2DataTable(string jdata)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;

        try {
            dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jdata, (typeof(DataTable)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("exception: " +ex.Message.ToString());

        }

        return dt;
    }
```

It is working for regular JSON objects and arrays.

But While working with some complex JSON object, am getting "Additional text found in JSON string after finishing de-serializing object."

Here is my sample JSON DATA

```
{
  "ads": {
    "items": [],
    "total": 0,
    "page": 1
  },
  "member": {
    "memberId": "649991",
    "displayName": "",
    "email": "hasaxxx@hotodeal.com",
    "memberStatus": "Y",
    "smiId": "7aa205ea-7aa2-7aa2-7aa2-7aa205eac183",
    "facebookId": "100001412016857",
    "registerDate": null,
    "emailConfirmed": false,
    "smsConfirmed": false,
    "facebookConfirmed": false,
    "lineId": null,
    "wechatId": null,
    "displayImage": "",
    "firstName": "Hasadin",
    "lastName": "Pankran",
    "telephone": "",
    "mobile": null,
    "listingCount": {
      "online": 0,
      "edit": 0,
      "waiting": 0
    },
    "phones": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because table/datatable represents simple data structure for complex data structure or relational model you should convert it to dataset instead of datatable.

JSON structure for converting into dataset should be like as follow:

```
{
    "ads": [{ 
         "total": 0, 
         "page": 1 
          }], 
    "member": [{
        "memberId": "649991",
        "displayName": "",
        "email": "hasaxxx@hotodeal.com",
        "memberStatus": "Y",
        "smiId": "7aa205ea-7aa2-7aa2-7aa2-7aa205eac183",
        "facebookId": "100001412016857",
        "registerDate": null,
        "emailConfirmed": false,
        "smsConfirmed": false,
        "facebookConfirmed": false,
        "lineId": null,
        "wechatId": null,
        "displayImage": "",
        "firstName": "Hasadin",
        "lastName": "Pankran",
        "telephone": "",
        "mobile": null 
        }] 
}
```